# Need to Display a Field Based on Search String

Tags: visualforce

We have a custom setting, countries code -> 2 fields are over there country Name and country code(length 2). Now the requirement is to create a VF Page where if I input country code as India it will display country code of India(i.e IN) when I click on button show country code.

I have written the VF but it didn't work. Please find the code below :

VF CODE :

```
<apex:page controller="CustomSettingExtension">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock Title="Search For Country Code" id="render" >
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search" columns="1">
              <apex:inputText label="Enter Country Name To Search" value="{!searchstring}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:pageblockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton value="Search" accesskey="{!Search}" reRender="render"/>
        </apex:pageblockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable var="cc" value="{!stringOutput}" >
            <apex:OutputField label="Country Code" value="{!cc.Country_Code__C}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>  
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

Controller Code :

```
public class CustomSettingExtension 
{

    public String getCountryList() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public string searchString{get;set;}
    public string countryCode{get;set;}
    public string stringOutput{get;set;}
    List<Country__C> countryList{get;set;}

    public CustomSettingExtension()
    {
        //Country__C countryCodevalue = Country__C.values('searchString');
        //this.countryCode = Country__C.getAll().values('searchString');
        //Games__c objGame = Games__c.getValues('My Games');
        countryList = new List<Country__C>();
        countryList = Country__C.getAll().values();
    }    

    public pagereference getsearch()
    {
        for(Country__C c : countryList)
        {
            countryCode = c.Country_Code__C;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string getstringOutput()
    {
        string ccode = Country__C.getInstance(searchString);
        return ccode;
    }

}
```

Please let me know where i am doing the wrong.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable var="cc" value="{!stringOutput}" >
```

getStringOutput returns a String, not a Country__c, and definitely not a *Collection*, which is what you're supposed to use. I presume this doesn't even compile, and if it does, it definitely doesn't work.

At minimum, change your markup:

```
<apex:page controller="CustomSettingExtension">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock Title="Search For Country Code" id="render" >
              <apex:pageblockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton value="Search" reRender="render" />
        </apex:pageblockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search" columns="1">
              <apex:inputText label="Enter Country Name To Search" value="{!searchstring}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Country Code" value="{!countryCode}" />
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

And your controller:

```
public String getCountryCode() {
  Country__c value = Country__c.getInstance(searchString);
  return value == null? null: value.Country_Code__c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Just a little update ---> I was getting error "Could not resolve the entity from <apex:outputField> value binding". Later after googling i came to know that, we can't bind controller property to an outputfield, only to an outputtext.  Output fields have to be bound to sobject fields.

Comment: @RaviRanjan Yeah, I just copy-pasted, and missed that.